# Display SOAP response from PHP form

Tags: php, soap, mysqli

I have a setup where a PHP form is posting a variable to be included in a SOAP request. The action goes to a PHP handler file which puts this variable into a database for yet another PHP functions file that sends the request and accepts the response XML. However, what I want is to parse this XML response and show output. Since the form goes to the handler.php and stays there while everything else processes I want to know if I can display the output that was sent to the functions.php file?

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.  It will help us understand your problem better and give you the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post simplified code example.

But you can also check the library documentation that handles the SOAP.
Because it can be the build in SOAP lib or a custom one.

For example  [get last soap request](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php)